# Vue is not installing using CLI

Tags: vue.js

I am installing Vue.js using CLI but every time I run `npm install -g @vue/cli` it returns the following error:
[image]

Comment: They are warnings, I dont see an error there.

Answer (score 0):

**Run npm list vue (or npm list --depth=0 | grep vue to exclude packages' dependencies). It is a common way to check npm package's version in the terminal**